# Finding related words with python

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to make a program that gives a bunch of words related to the input.

For example:

the input is Artificial Intelligence and the related words would be:

AI,A.I., Machine Learning, Deep Learning, etc. but not words like Military Programme and Artificial Insemination.

I've seen the NLTK library and several API's but I don't really know where to start.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you follow the tutorial on http://www.nltk.org/?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Because I don't hava a problem with how it works but finding a starting point on the problem I'm trying to solve